# решено Python3: После рекурсии TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '...'

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./zelobar/zelobari3test.py", line 26, in <module>
    r(conn.get_tree())
  File "/home/drmgc/dev/prj/zelobar/zelobar/i3.py", line 680, in get_tree
    return Container.from_dict(json.loads(data))
  File "/home/drmgc/dev/prj/zelobar/zelobar/i3.py", line 452, in from_dict
    nodes.append(cls.from_dict(n))
  File "/home/drmgc/dev/prj/zelobar/zelobar/i3.py", line 452, in from_dict
    nodes.append(cls.from_dict(n))
  File "/home/drmgc/dev/prj/zelobar/zelobar/i3.py", line 452, in from_dict
    nodes.append(cls.from_dict(n))
  File "/home/drmgc/dev/prj/zelobar/zelobar/i3.py", line 468, in from_dict
    nodes=nodes)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'border'
```

И каждый раз выскакивает новая (т.е. сейчас `border`, а потом с другими, н-р `geometry` или `deco_rect`).

PS http://pastebin.com/e1rJhy3b

PPS Python 3.4, Debian 8

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Перепутал Container и Workspace

Comment: новая ошибка может возникать из-за того что словари в Питоне не упорядочены и порядок ключей может меняться от запуска к запуску.

Comment: Если решили -- выберите/напишите помогший ответ и отметьте его галочкой под голосовалкой.

Answer (score 1):

Я совсем не хочу разбираться в вашем коде но сигнатура конструктора Workspace на 141 строке, совсем не совпадает с тем что вы вызываете на  454 стоке. О чем собственно говоря и сообщает ошибка.

Почему питон сыпется с ругательствами на разные аргументы (а их вы даете в 2 раза больше чем определено в конструкторе) с разными ошибками я не подскажу. Сам наблюдаю тоже поведение в самом тривиальном случае.

```
 class Workspace:
   def __init__(self):pass

 wsp = Workspace(a="1", b="2")
```

Comment: а, всё нашел, я вместо Container написал Workspace (копипастил). Второй раз уже.